# How to get the last changed object in django-simple-history?

Tags: django-simple-history

Using [django-simple-history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history), how can I get the last changed object from my model?

I tried `MyModel.history.most_recent()`, which needs a model instance, so that returns probably the most recent version of a selected instance.

I can query `Abonnent.history.all()`, which obviously returns a list of all versions of all model objects. This looks good, but how can I filter out the most recent and get the date of the last change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If MyModel.history is a HistoricalRecords objects you access like: 
`MyModel.history.last()`

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
from datetime import datetime

poll.history.as_of(datetime(2010, 10, 25, 18, 4, 0))
<Poll: Poll object as of 2010-10-25 18:03:29.855689>

poll.history.as_of(datetime(2010, 10, 25, 18, 5, 0))
<Poll: Poll object as of 2010-10-25 18:04:13.814128>
```